# Is "distance" an "amount" or a "quantity"?

Tags: word-choice, quantifiers

Distance can be measured so it would make sense for it to be a quantity. But this is where I arrive at an issue.

I think it's better if you say

> a small amount of distance

than

> a small quantity of distance

I don't know which one is correct or which one is used more widely. The first phrase would make more sense to me but I'm not sure why. Could someone enlighten me on whether distance is an "amount" or a "quantity"

Comment: Neither. We say 'a short distance', 'a great height', as with say 'a low temperature', 'a long time'.  You seem to have picked up a rule somewhere; either the rule is wrong, or you're misapplying it.

Comment: I'm basing this on "modicum of distance" where "modicum" means a small/limited **quantity** of something. ([modicum definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modicum))

This phrase has been used by the New York Times. You can find it [here](https://ludwig.guru/s/a+modicum+of+distance).

Comment: Those don't use the prototypical sense of 'distance'. 'Distance' there is a synonym of 'separation'.

Comment: I see... That's where my confusion comes from then.